# Update Multiple Tables Using One Data and Query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update, sql-delete

I'm trying to update multiple tables' rows using one query where `thread_id` and `threadfrn_id` are provided.
But it seems like if the row with `threadfrn_id = 460` in the `files` table doesn't exist, then the update does not happen, even for the `threads` table. 
Anyone have a solution to this one?

**MySQL**

```
UPDATE threads,files SET threads.del = 1,  files.del = 1 
WHERE threads.thread_id=460  AND files.threadfrn_id=460
```

**P.S** What I'm trying to do is, `Update` the `del` column so that I can later delete the rows with `del = 1` from the tables.

Comment: why don't you do it in 2 statements?

Comment: If i have to Update 10 tables it can be slow as Hell. ! @vkp

Answer (score 0):

Try below Query:

```
UPDATE T
SET T.del = 1,  OT.del = 1 
FROM threads T
INNER JOIN  files OT
ON T.thread_id = OT.threadfrn_id
and T.thread_id = 460 and OT.threadfrn_id = 460
```

Comment: Try this:UPDATE threads,files SET threads.del = 1,  files.del = 1 
WHERE 
threads.thread_id=460  AND files.threadfrn_id=460

Comment: Dang! This is just the same thing which i did! @amit!

Answer (score 0):

Include the `join` in the `WHERE` clause.

```
UPDATE threads,files SET threads.del = 1,  files.del = 1 
WHERE --include join condition for the tables
and threads.thread_id=460  AND files.threadfrn_id=460
```

Or you can do it in 2 statements

```
UPDATE threads SET del = 1 where thread_id=460;
UPDATE files SET del = 1 where threadfrn_id=460;
```